# parallely run an application while it starts another application in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write an application program that can start another application using c++ in linux . Starting another application is not the problem . The problem I am facing is, that the parent application pauses till the child application is closed. I want the parent application to run along with the child application so that more functionalities of the parent application can be used. How do i go about it? 
It would help me a lot if somebody could give me an idea on this.

The application consists of two files main.cpp and a virtualbotmain.cpp. The part of the

```
 virtualbotmain.cpp: #include <iostream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 VirtualBotMain::VirtualBotMain(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::VirtualBotMain)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
void VirtualBotMain::on_enterButton_clicked()
{
QString enterString = ui->enterEdit->text();
ui->convoText->append("User: " + enterString);
ui->enterEdit->setText("");
if(enterString=="word")
{
    ui->convoText->append("Joe: done..!!");
    system("gedit");

}
```

}

The main.cpp is :

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "virtualbotmain.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
VirtualBotMain w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

This is a GUI application that can be used to just type in the application i am trying to open and the application will do it for me. So trying to open many applications one after the other is becoming a problem as the GUI application won't work untill i close the previously opened application.

Comment: show your code, please!

Comment: in linux, look into fork()

Comment: On posix systems like linux the spawn family of functions is preferred.  Pass P_NOWAIT as mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a `system` call (or a similar way to invoke the shell), you can apply the same logic you'd apply in your terminal to start a process "in the background":

```
system("./myProgram &");
//                  ^
//           run in background
```

Better alternatives include [`fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)ing, though it really depends on your specific requirements, which we do not know.

Comment: What does it do?.I mean ,can i use the parent GUI application after it starts another process??

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <process.h>

int status = spawnl( P_NOWAIT, "myprog", "myprog", "ARG1", "ARG2", NULL );
```

Comment: i don't know anything about this spawnl() function. Could you elaborate please??

Comment: It is used to launch processes.  Here is some docs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_(computing)

Comment: arguments don't wait for the process to exit, name of process, then command line arguments.  There are others in the spawn family that may better suit your use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! even  though system("./Myprog &") solves my problem for now but I hope spawn gives me a better way to code my project..!! Thanks a lot ..!!